# mv command - lost files - directory turned into a file

Tags: command-line, mv

I am starting to learn about linux commands, and today i did something, that I can't find the solution nowhere !

I tried to move a file "test.txt" to the "Subfolder2", to do so, I entered the following statement:

```
mv test.txt ~/Folder1/subfolder2
```

now I noticed that in the command above, a entered "subfolder2" with a lowercase, and apparently I created a file with the name "subfolder2" !  Worse, I have no longer acess to the file that I have moved!

I would apreaciatte any help to solve this!

Comment: Your file is named `subfolder2` and it is to be found in `~/Folder1`. This did not affect the directory `~/Folder1/Subfolder2` in any way. (Most filesystems used on Linux do not confuse `Subfolder2` with `subfolder2`.) To move it back, say `mv ~/Folder1/subfolder2 test.txt`.

Comment: @AlexP, that should be an answer!

Comment: Yes. I think you are right ! I renamed the file to subfolder2,  thanks for the clarification. But the problem is that i did that to 2 files:
mv test.txt ~/Folder1/subfolder2
mv test2.txt ~/Folder1/subfolder2

If i am getting it right I lost the first file ? its was overwritten by test2.txt (renamed to subfolder2) ? 
Thanks again !

Comment: @Alex is correct. It should be changed to answer so you can approve it. Run ls - la to see permissions. Unlikely your file named subfolder2 has restrictive permissions, unless you fiddled the umask in your session before this. There is a way to cause new files to be unwritable, but unlikely you would tickle that funny spot.

Comment: I am sorry, I am fairly new to this, how can I approve it to be an answer?

Comment: When AlexP posts an actual answer, then you can tick the "accepted" checkmark. Comments are just that, they don't count as actually an answer

Comment: And yes, if you moved test.txt first, then test2.txt, the original file is gone. Unless of course it's still open by some program, then its contents should be recoverable from RAM or more specifically `/proc` filesystem. But likely it's gone